# Rails - Mass-Assignment ForbiddenAttributesError for nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, mass-assignment

I'm having an issue with mass assignment for nested attributes. I'm having a hash in params that represents an object that results from a `form_for` form.

I tried to authorize the params like this but I get the following error...

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

for

```
params.require(:country).permit(:language, :flag_path)
@country.update(params[:country])
```

Here is the params array :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxx",
 "country"=>{"language"=>"xxxx",
 "flag_path"=>"xxxxx"},
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "country_id"=>"xxxx"}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : I know it is possible to user `permit!` but if I understand correctly, this authorize all parameters for the ressource and I'd like to permit only some of it.

Comment: Can you show your CountriesController code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1st:
Consider if below is your permit param method in your controller :

```
def country_param
  params.require(:country).permit(:language, :flag_path)
end
```

then your update action should be like this:

```
@country.update(country_param)
```

not

```
@country.update(params[:country])
```

2nd: Why you have `country_id` in your update action. It should be `id` instead.
It's not big one both will work. But with `country_id` You will not reach to proper edit action.

Anyway according to your params your action should be look like:

```
def update
  @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
  @country.update(country_param)
end

private

  def country_param
    params.require(:country).permit(:language, :flag_path)
  end
```

Comment: Seems that I didn't understand the permission. Now I do.
The only thing I do not understand is the id thing...

Comment: Hi Dipak, Do we need required if I don't have it and also I have to permit with hash eg: a lots of key=>value for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/43463680/3528013 Thk.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with `params.require(:country).permit` is the correct way to do it. `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` will be raised if any one of the params is not permitted so it is likely that you have missed off one of the params.

Check all of the params in your params hash and make sure that they have been permitted, it looks like `commit` and `contry_id` are missing, for example.