# Mass assignment in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I tried to upgrade [Mindapp](https://github.com/kul1/f241502) Gem  from  Rails 4 to Rails 5. There are a lots of codes like below need to be fixed because Rails 5.1 no longer support mass assignment to_bson directly.

```
Mindapp::Xmain.create :service=>service,
                          :start=>Time.now,
                          :name=>service.name,
                          :ip=> get_ip,
                          :status=>'I', # init
                          :user=>current_user,
                          :xvars=> {
                              :service_id=>service.id, :p=>params,
                              :id=>params[:id],
                              :user_id=>current_user.try(:id),
                              :custom_controller=>custom_controller,
                              :host=>request.host,
                              :referer=>request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
                          }
```

Then error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Method to_bson is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, as `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from hash. Using this deprecated behavior exposes potential security problems. If you continue to use this method you may be creating a security vulnerability in your app that can be exploited. Instead, consider using one of these documented methods which are not deprecated: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html
```

To [comply with Rails 5.1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.2/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) from this WARNING: I put params (without understand really) to:

```
  Mindapp::Xmain.create(xmain_params)
  def xmain_params
            params.permit(
                          :service=>service,
                          :start=>Time.now,
                          :name=>service.name,
                          :ip=> get_ip,
                          :status=>'I', # init
                          :user=>current_user,
                          :xvars=> {
                              :service_id=>service.id, :p=>params,
                              :id=>params[:id],
                              :user_id=>current_user.try(:id),
                              :custom_controller=>custom_controller,
                              :host=>request.host,
                              :referer=>request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
                          }
            )
  end
```

Problem: It's not create as supposed to do. 
This code (before modified) work in rails 4 but Warning in 5.0 and Now not work in Rails 5.1 all using Ruby 2.4.1.
What should I do/Thanks

And when tried

```
 Mindapp::Xmain.create :service=>params.permit(service),
                      :start=>params.permit(Time.now),
                      :name=>params.permit(service.name),
                      :ip=>params.permit(get_ip),
                      :status=>params.permit('I'), # init
                      :user=>params.permit(current_user),
                      :xvars=> params.permit({
                          :service_id=>service.id, :p=>params,
                          :id=>params[:id],
                          :user_id=>current_user.try(:id),
                          :custom_controller=>custom_controller,
                          :host=>request.host,
                          :referer=>request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
                      })
```

Errors:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue - 
message:
  Value of type ActionController::Parameters cannot be written to a field of type Hash
summary:
  Tried to set a value of type ActionController::Parameters to a field of type Hash
resolution:
  Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition:
```

And try using params.

```
Mindapp::Xmain.create :service=>params.service,
                      :start=>params.Time.now,
                      :name=>params.service.name,
                      :ip=> params.get_ip,
                      :status=>params('I'), # init
                      :user=>params.current_user,
                      :xvars=> {
                          :service_id=>params.service.id, :p=>params,
                          :id=>params[:id],
                          :user_id=>params.current_user.try(:id),
                          :custom_controller=>params.custom_controller,
                          :host=>params.request.host,
                          :referer=>params.request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
                      }
```

Errors:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `service' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007ff6b07158f0>:
  actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:646:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/mindapp_controller.rb:384:in `create_xmain'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `:p=>params`. I'm assuming `params` is a params object from the request. Under Rails 5.1, it will no longer support standard hash functions such as `to_bson`, which mindapp library appears to be using (or maybe one of its dependent libraries is using it).

A simple fix is probably to replace it with `:p=>params.to_unsafe_hash` or for a safer solution, `:p=>params.permit(:foo, :bar)` (whatever params should be used, these should possibly be checked/cleansed first).

Comment: So :service=>service would be :service=>params.permit(:service) and so on then I get Mongoid::Errors::InvalidValue - 
message:
  Value of type ActionController::Parameters cannot be written to a field of type Hash
summary:
  Tried to set a value of type ActionController::Parameters to a field of type Hash
resolution:
  Verify if the value to be set correspond to field definition:

Comment: I tested  params.to_unsafe_hash but error undefined method as updated above.

Comment: You could try params[:service] instead of params.service. Also you don't need params for 'I' and Time.now etc. Just use params[:foo] where you need to access an attribute from params hash.

Comment: You might want to start by hard-coding all hash values so that you make a successful call to the XMain constructor, without any params at all. Then gradually replace it with params where you want to rely on the params.

Comment: Yes I read all the link seem talking about this. Except I just move to rails. I don't think I can easily do that but will go by each hash and test result. Hope I can put it all together. Thanks